# PHP Header Redirect Using Variable

Tags: php, forms

Hoping someone can help me figure out how to dynamically update a php header redirect in my mail handler file using a variable.

**What I was using in my PHP mail handler:**

```
header('Location: filename.php');
```

**What I tried to do:**

**Front End File**

```
$tyTarget = "filename.php";

<input type="hidden" name="redirDestination" value="<?php echo $tyTarget ?>" />
```

**PHP Mail Handler**

```
$thankYou = $_POST['redirDestination'];

header('Location: $thankYou');
```

**Background:**

I'm templating out a few landing pages.  They use a standard HTML form that passes a couple of hidden inputs that we use internally.  Historically, each landing page had its own PHP mail handler which we'd simply use a header redirect on submit to its own thank you page (i.e. thank-you-facebook.php or thank-you-email.php) which gets used for conversion tracking for each source.

Working to consolidate a bunch of these pages and use a few PHP includes to simplify the template but dynamically loading the redirect target from a variable didn't work.

Do I just have a syntax error in my redirect?

Any help is appreciated.  PHP noob.

**Update per duplicate question flag:**
As someone who spent a while looking for answers to this question before posting, flagging this as a duplicate question because the correct answer loosely fell in line with a question regarding single quotes in PHP would not have helped me find the answer.  In other words, the question was different and not a duplicate.  The solution accepted as the answer just happened to be similar.

Comment: `header('Location: $thankYou');` is using single quotes. You would want `header('Location: '. $thankYou);`

Comment: or `header("Location: $thankYou");`

Comment: Yeah that works too @nogad! I personally shy away from double quotes with included variables, as php is then trying to interpret the whole string for variables and code.

Comment: @Randall just dont call it "faster" :-)

Comment: Right. My reasoning isnt about speed, but more of "oops I put too much in that string and I'm getting unexpected results because php decided my dollar amounts are a variable" ;-) More operator error, than a speed issue haha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Judging from your code paste, your issue is a simple syntax goof. You have:

```
header('Location: $thankYou');
```

Which is using single quotes around the variable. You would want:

```
header('Location: '. $thankYou);
```

Comment: This absolutely works.  I'll give you credit for the answer as soon as the timer is up.

I'm not sure I understand the difference between the double and single quotes in this case.  I'll go back to the book and see what I come up with, but if you've got any high-level insight you want to share, I'm trying to grasp this more than "hey, that works!" =).

Comment: @sforcash some light reading: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3446216/what-is-the-difference-between-single-quoted-and-double-quoted-strings-in-php

Comment: @nogad exactly what I was looking for.  Thanks bud.